# How do I define a custom OpenLDAP schema without built-ins?

Tags: ldap, openldap

I'm defining a custom **LDAP** schema for use with **OpenLDAP**. The schema is fairly simple and very domain-specific, and therefore (nearly) all the built-in attributes and object classes are unnecessary and just getting in the way.  So, how do I configure OpenLDAP such that it only takes into account my schema and ignores all the rest?

Comment: Don't load any of the other schemas?

Comment: I may be missing something, but when run `slaptest` using my custom config file which only contains my schema, the generated config contains a ton of other attributes.

Comment: Well you can't get rid of the built-in ones, because they are, err, built-in.